# why cant I add decimals to solr

Tags: php, solr

I'm trying to add docs to my solr core (using Solarium for php).

I have a field defined in my schema as:

```
<field name="salarymin"
    type="currency"
    indexed="true"
    stored="true"
    multiValued="false"
    required="false" />
```

But when I try to add a doc with a salarymin value of '7.48' (or any value with a decimal) I get an error:

```
 Error adding field 'salarymin'='7.48' msg=For input string: \"7.48\""
```

Answer (score 0):

What "currency" type is ?

I guess you use some thing like

```
 <fieldType class="solr.CurrencyField" name="currencyField" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currencyExchange.xml" />
```

I guess you miss some part of value. I guess correct one should be like 29.99,USD

Please look on this - http://solr.pl/en/2012/03/19/solr-3-6-currencyfield-2/